# Where does the Camera app save videos?

Tags: windows-8, video-capture

When a video is recorded in Camera, where is it saved to?

I can't find them in the Videos or Pictures folders. They're not in the Public folders either.

They don't even show up in the Windows Store App, Videos.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your Pictures library should contain a Camera Roll folder where these images and videos are stored.

Comment: That folder isn't on my system.

Comment: Hm, I've also seen 'Camera Roll' and 'C:/Users/Public/Pictures' on the internet. Have you got those?

Comment: ha, yeah I actually just finished searching for it (`kind:=video datemodified:today`). It is indeed in Camera Roll.

Comment: ....for the record this should be put in the "video" directory. Its unintuitive. But hey, thats win8 apps for ya ;)

Comment: The save location can vary on different machines - see my answer for where to find the save location on yours

Comment: @Peter, **How can we change the location?**

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry, I don't really know + I've moved to Windows 10. But this might help you: https://superuser.com/questions/502117/change-location-of-where-pictures-videos-are-saved-using-the-camera-app-in-windo

Answer (score 11):

I believe it's this directory:

```
C:\Users\(your user)\Pictures\Camera Roll
```

Comment: This is where the camera app stored my video with `Windows 10`.  I was confused because I expect the video to be stored in the `Videos` subfolder instead.

Answer (score 1):

I found that mine were being saved to the OneDrive folder in my Users folder.  In the Camera app, the ellipsis ... menu includes a Settings option - this takes you to the part of Windows Settings that lets you specify default save locations.

In there you'll find the save location for your specific machine, whether it's OneDrive or other, and you can change it to your preferred location.