# Change location of where pictures/videos are saved using the Camera App in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, camera, file-location

Does anyone know how I can change the location of where pictures/videos are saved using the Camera App in Windows 8?

I've had a look in the hidden and very difficult to get into "Windows Apps" folder but have had no luck.

Comment: Are you searching for where the files are saved, or you're trying to change it?

Comment: Does anyone know how I can **change** the location of where pictures/videos are saved using the Camera App in Windows 8?

Comment: You could probably change the default save location of your pictures library. then it will save pictures in <your default location>/Camera Roll

Answer (score 3):

The camera app - just like the music and video apps in Windows 8 - rely on the Windows Libraries (in this case the "Pictures" library).

Each library can have multiple folders + 1 folder for saving new data. So the camera app will save photos to the default saving location of your "Pictures" library.

If you want to change that, open Windows Explorer ([Win] + [E]); in the left pane right-click on the pictures library, click properties. There you can add or remove folders and set any of these folders as saving location.

Note that the camera app in particular will create a sub-folder, I have not found a way to change that behavior.

Comment: The sub-directory mentioned by Akinzekeel is the "Camera Roll" directory. In particular look for \Pictures\Camera Roll. If you're like me and have a ton of sub-directories in your pictures library, it's easy to miss this! :)

Comment: This may simply be that I'm trying to use a network location; however, this information is not working. I have removed all of the items from the picture library except for my network location and it is set as the default save location. The camera still places the images into %USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Camera Roll